# Angular 2 template parse error in PhantomJS?

Tags: angular, phantomjs

I have a problem when write unit test for component in angular 2:

[image]

This error only show when run test, Good run on chrome.

Any help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This error only show when run test

Just like you import `ReactiveFormModule` into your application modules, you also need to do so for the test. What `TestBed.configureTestingModule` is for is to configure a module (just like `@NgModule`) *from scratch* for the test environment. So if you are using forms in the component that you are testing, then you need to add the forms module, just like you would in the application

```
beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule ],
    declarations: [ MessageFormComponent ],
    providers: []
  })
})
```